# Linkedin Integration in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios-simulator

Im trying to integrate Linkedin network in my iphone app.I searched sample codes and i found one sample code in github

https://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone

I downloaded the sample code and provided consumer and secret keys.It works good.When im trying to do this in my app,its not working.So many errors saying rdEngine.h--no such directory or file.But i imported linkedin library xcode to my app.How to import frameworks and liraries to my app?What i have to do to integrate linkedin in iphone?I want to update status of a linkedin of a user from iphone directly and i want to display the latest status of a linkedin in iphone .Please suggest me any possible ways to do this...Also tell me what are the steps i need to follow to do this.Thank you in advance..

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have already suggest you that set your HEADER SEARCH PATH, is it correct

Comment: yes.As i already told u,i solved this issue.But twitter and linkedin together not working.Same error as u got.Did u solved your problem?

Comment: thanks for accepting....if you can please check .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297783

Comment: yes solved the problem...

I done one thing that is ... I remove the library files of linkedin sdk.. and add the source files of it with oAuth files from twiiter sdk... then it works ok for linkedin i.imgur.com/cXLXU.png i.imgur.com/ntV9G.png ....then I integrate all twitter code then project run ok without error but for twitter login interface it shows PAGE NOT FOUND ..i.imgur.com/8a1ua.png – Amit Battan 6 hours ago .....then
solved now...I have given the same key and secret to both linkedin and twitter ..after changing them it works

Comment: hey are you able to login into your demo application.... actually I am not... where I have to enter the security code

Comment: I will check and i will tell u tommorrow

Comment: Hi,im trying to integrate linkedin,twitter and facebook in ipad app.So im able to see the security code.I have done in iphone also..as u said,the security code is not visible.But i dont know where to enter the security code.Im sending 2 screen shots..

Comment: solution is here https://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone/issues/9/#comment_874240

Comment: do one think ..please edit your question and add these images in the end after Edit Label so that anyone can easily understand question and assume that images are added later after editing

Comment: hey,how u returned back to your appliation so as to enter security code?I tried to return by clicking on close button.But there is a http status saying not available.(as on 1st image)

Comment: check the post https://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone/issues/9/#comment_874240

Comment: start a new question as it is new issue .. no one see the question after accepting request... start new question .. then others can also check it

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the material and sample from this [Link](https://github.com/synedra/LinkedIn-OAuth-Sample-Client) github repo,and you have to set up your header Path in your xcode environment as below to remove some hmac.h file not found type error

1. Go to the project > Targets > Build Settings
2. Search Header Search Paths
3. Add
4. $(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2

It is working in my iphone application with LinkedIn status update,Hope it will help you