# Linkedin Successfull Authrized Interface on Iphone

Tags: api, iphone-sdk-3.0, linkedin-api

I am using the LinkedIn iOS SDK using oAuth in my IPhone application.
Its integarted successfully but After login it goes to Success Authrized Screen as in images

[image]
[image]

I have 2 issue

- UIWebView showing the interface like in zoom(Not zoom exactly its not showing properly.. cutting something from left side as in image). Security Code not showing properly as in screen-shots.
- Where is the place for enter the security code and "OK" button. How we enter the security code. and come back to my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out
http://developer.linkedin.com/message/8675#8675

If you are not using an oauth callback, the user will need to return to your application themselves and input the token for you to use for verification.  If you are using a callback, the user will never see the PIN screen.  See the documentation on Using OAuth with the LinkedIn APIs for more information.

Comment: Solved idea from https://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone/issues/9/#comment_874240

Comment: check it in application settings in linkedIn website.